# Update managerId for for different employee

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp, select

I have Reporting_officers Table.structure of table is below

```
R_id    User_id Manager_id  Managre2_id
1        4       3        3
2        3       2        2
3        5       3        2
```

now i want update user_id 3 to 6 in this table, then it should reflect to manager_id and manger2_id which have  3 
like below

```
R_id    User_id   Manager_id  Managre2_id
 1          4         6           6
 2          6         2           2
 3          5         6           2
```

Comment: Question not good plzz improve.

Comment: @Meghana your question is not clear and post what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this query is working perfect you can check it on sql fiddle
[table strutured](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1cc52/1)

[table after dml](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c8098/1)

```
UPDATE 
  `Reporting_officers`  
SET
  `Manager_id` = NULL
WHERE Reporting_officers.`Manager_id` = 3;

UPDATE 
  `Reporting_officers`  
SET
  `Managre2_id` = NULL
WHERE `Managre2_id` = 3;


UPDATE 
  `Reporting_officers`  
SET
  User_id = 6 
WHERE `User_id` = 3;


UPDATE 
  `Reporting_officers` 
SET
  `Manager_id` = CASE WHEN Manager_id IS NULL  THEN 6 ELSE Manager_id END,
  `Managre2_id` = CASE WHEN Managre2_id IS NULL  THEN 6 ELSE Managre2_id END
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to define your table with a foreign key that has an `on update cascade` clause, so the database can handle all the heavy lifting for you, and all you need to do is update the `user_id`:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    r_id int,
    user_id int,
    manager_id int,
    manager2_id int,
    PRIMARY KEY (r_id),
    CONSTRAINT users_id_uk UNIQUE (user_id)
    FOREIGN KEY users_manager_id_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (manager_id)
        REFERENCES `users` (user_id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY users_manager2_id_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (manager2_id)
        REFERENCES `users` (user_id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```